# How does this work: except IOError as e: print("No such file: {0.filename}".format(e))

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code that uses the expression in question:

```
def read_file(self,file_name):
        try:
            with open(file_name,'r') as file:
                data=file.read()
                return data.split()

        except IOError as e:
            print("Could not read file:{0.filename}".format(e))
            sys.exit()
```

How does this work? What is meaning of `{0.filename}.format(e)`? Why do we use `{0.filename}` and not `{1.filename}`?

Comment: You should write the code that is raising the error

Comment: Added the full code @Jalo

Comment: @Jalo: Additional code is not needed here as the given code is concise and generic for exception raised situation.

Comment: @Abhineet You are right, but I realized it after seeing the edit

Comment: @Jalo:: Anyways, no harm done with extra codes :)

Comment: You could just as easily use `print("Could not read file:", e.filename)` and not have to worry about it or indeed `print("Could not read file:", e)`

Comment: Now that's the beauty of python  . One thing can be done in many ways . Thanks @RolfofSaxony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This essentially means takes the positional argument at position `0` (in `format(e)`, `e` is the zero position arg)  and grab the `filename` attribute defined on it:

```
print("No such file: {0.filename}".format(e))
```

Is similar to:

```
print("No such file: {0}".format(e.filename))
```

It isn't `1.filename` because format hasn't been called with an argument at position `1`, another example might help you out even more:

```
print("{0}{1.filename}".format("No such File: ", e))
```

Here `{0}` will grab `"No such File: "` and `{1.filename}` will grab `e.filename` and add it to the resulting string.

Comment: Thanks @Jim . could you suggest me some online/offline resources to get familiar with exception handling(for python3)

Comment: Python docs will be a good place to start:: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Thanks mate @Abhineet ^_^

Comment: There's a tutorial in the Python Docs on [Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) where you could start. The specification for the syntax in format strings can also be found [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Comment: Maybe you 're looking for an explanation of [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: Thank you all . ^_^